Is it possible to tell what aircraft this is?
On a flight a few years ago, I got this picture. Is it possible to tell the aircraft by just this image? I’ve found a few similar but they are a bit different than this one. Someone I was with said they saw “Airbus” on the headrests of the seats, but I’m not sure because I didn’t.



When trying to find it myself, it kind of looks like the wing of the A320 or A321. But then it also looks like the wing of some 737’s.
I know that there are some planes that use the same wing as others, so this might not be possible to tell.

Additional information:
The airline was JetBlue (relevant because some airlines don’t operate certain planes)
It had 2 seats on each side of the cabin
The flight lasted around 1 hour (Different planes are used for longer or shorter haul flights)

My guess: A type of 737.

If you still have any documentation from the flight (e.g. the e-mail sent out when you purchased the ticket), you can probably confirm exactly what type of plane it was.  Ticket stub or boarding pass would also have it, but people are less likely to hold onto those for that long.

Can't be a 737, those have today a 3+3 seat configuration, not 2+2 (unless maybe some VIP versions?)

@kebs yeah you’re correct. I was just going off of the wing geometry, but I should’ve seen the seat config as well.

It's an EMB-190. Jetblue only flies two aircraft with two seats on each side of an aisle, the A220 and the EMB190.
Looking the wing underside the EMB-190 has three flap track fairings and one engine pylon fairing visible at the wing trailing edge.

The A220 has only the three flap track fairings visible, the engine pylon ends midway back under the wing and is not visible.


According to this source, Jet Blue operates a fleet of A220, A320, A321, ERJ190.
Do you remember the seating arrangement in coach?  Most likely a 3-3 (3 seats on either side of a single aisle) arrangement, but if it was a 2-1, 3-2, or a 2-2, that would be significant.
From looking at some of the photos, it looks to me like an ERJ-190.
This photo shows the paint job on the upper surface of the wing.
The other most similar contender is the A321-200, but the leading edge of the winglets on those is left un-painted.

Yeah it had 2 seats on each side of the cabin. I think it is in fact a 190, considering the other answer. Thanks.
